# Python: Trim strings in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column dataframe that I would like to trim the leading and trailing parts to it. The column has contents such as: `['Tim [Boy]', 'Gina [Girl]'...]` and I would like it to make a new column that just has `['Boy','Girl'... etc.]`. I tried using `rstrip` and `lstrip` but have had no luck. Please advise. Thank you

Comment: Please provide an example dataframe, either as DataFrame constructor or as dictionary (`df.to_dict()`), your current description is ambiguous. Please also provide the expected output in the same format

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the cells of the column are `'Tim [Boy]'`, etc.

Such as in:

```
  name_gender
0   AAa [Boy]
1  BBc [Girl]
```

You want to use a replace method call passing a regular expression to pandas.

Assuming that your dataframe is called `df`, the original column name is `'name_gender'` and the destination (new column) name is `'gender'`, you can use the following code:

```py
df['gender'] = df['name_gender'].replace('.*\\[(.*)\\]', '\\1', regex=True)
```

or as suggested by @mozway below, this can also be written as:

```py
df['gender'] = df['name_gender'].str.extract('.*\\[(.*)\\]')
```

You end up with:

```
  name_gender gender
0   AAa [Boy]    Boy
1  BBc [Girl]   Girl
```

The regexp `'.*\\[(.*)\\]'` can be interpreted as matching anything, plus a '[', plus anything which is stored into a register (that's what the parentheses are there for), and a ']'. This is replaced then (second regexp) with the thing stored into register 1 (the only used in the matching regexp).

You might want to document yourself on regexps if you don't know them.

Anything which does not match the entry will not be replaced. You might want to add a test to detect whether some rows don't match that pattern ("name [gender]").

Comment: `df['name_gender'].str.extract(r'\[(.*)\]')` should work fine as well

Comment: @ddejohn if you do *not* match the characters before the things in brackets, they won't be replaced and remain in the output (giving e,g. `AAa Boy`). I could add ^ and $ markers at the beginning and the end of the regexp to make the behaviour tighter.

Comment: @mozway Did not know the extract method. Pandas has such a large set of methods. Thanks.

Comment: feel free to add to your answer if you want to ;)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your help!